# Export Jupyter Notebook to Python file in visual code

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to export my Juypter Notebook to .py to be able to debug it but with no success.
In this [page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support#_debug-a-jupyter-notebook) they explained how to export a Notebook to .py, but in my environment I have no such option.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known regression in the Jupyter extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/5403). We have fixed this and will release a fix for the Jupyter extension in VS Code Stable sometime this week. In the meantime you can access the export to Python feature by switching to [VS Code Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/), which will allow you to download a nightly build of the Jupyter extension that already contains the fix. Sorry for the trouble!

Additionally, if it's debugging that you're after, you can debug individual notebook cells using our Run By Line feature. In the screenshot you posted, simply click on the second button in your cell toolbar to start debugging that cell.

Comment: Hi, I used to have this Run By Line button, but after updating to 1.57.1, the button disappeared. Did you remove it? How can I achieve a similar function? Thank you.

Comment: @Betty You've likely been opted into the preview native notebooks interface, where Run By Line hasn't been implemented yet (work is currently in progress: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/126431). If you need to use Run By Line, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67142271/visual-studio-jupyter-notebook/67145446#67145446 for how to opt back into the old interface.