# VS Code: jupyter notebook run line by line

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

Recently VSCode got an update and after that my jupyter notebook interface has changed which created a lot of problems for me. Now I don't know how to run cell code line by line, etc.

Is there any other way to do so or how can I get back to an older version of the notebook?

Answer (score 2):

1. Open the command palette (Ctrl+Shift+P on Windows, Cmd+Shift+P on Mac)
2. Type 'Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)' and select the first option to open your user settings.json file
   [image: Command palette]
3. Add the following line to your user settings.json file:

```json
"jupyter.experiments.optOutFrom": ["NativeNotebookEditor"],
```

4. If the following entry is present in your user settings.json file, **delete** it:

```json
"workbench.editorAssociations": [
  {
    "viewType": "jupyter-notebook",
    "filenamePattern": "*.ipynb"
  }
]
```

5. Reload Visual Studio Code for the new settings to take effect. You should be opted back into the old Jupyter notebook interface.

Answer (score 1):

In v1.60 (see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_60.md#jupyter):

> VS Code now supports the Run By Line feature in Jupyter notebooks.
> This is a simple debug mode that lets you execute the code of a cell
> line by line. To try it out, just make sure that you have `ipykernel v6+` installed as your selected kernel, then select the **Run By Line**
> button.

---

Previously:

In vscode 1.59 (see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_59.md#jupyter-run-by-line)

> #### Jupyter "Run By Line"
>
> We've been working on supporting the "Run By Line" feature in Jupyter
> notebooks. This feature is essentially a simplified debug mode that
> lets you step through your cell's code line by line without any
> complex debug UI. This is still experimental, but you can try it out
> by setting `"jupyter.experimental.debugging": true`, installing
> version 6 of ipykernel in your selected kernel, then clicking the "Run
> By Line" button in the cell toolbar.

`"jupyter.experimental.debugging": true`

---

Answer (score 1):

[image]

If you want to run a python script line by line using Jupyter interpreter this is the option you need to tick in VS code settings.

Comment: Here I made a feature request to run selection in jupyter notebooks: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/200625 If you like it, please support by giving it a 