# Where is plot viewer with the updated jupyter notebook (June 30, 2021)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I used to use the plot viewer feature in vs code's jupyter notebook quite a bit. In the updated design, the little logo does not show up in the top left corner for matplotlib figures anymore. How do you view a high res pdf version of matplotlib figures?

Edit: [This is the view I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGF9j.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a developer on this extension. The plot viewer has not yet been implemented for the new native notebooks interface. We are planning to add it back for the August release, but in the meantime you can manually switch back to the old UI with plot viewer support by [following the instructions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67142271/visual-studio-jupyter-notebook/67145446#67145446).

Comment: Cool, thanks! It's a very useful feature so I hope its added soon. I think the rest of the new UI looks good though.

Answer (score 0):

The logo appears to me. you might want to reinstall the jupyter notebook extension.

[image: hoover]

Comment: This is what I used to see! It must have updated because the entire UI seems a little different. I've updated the question with an image of what I see.

Answer (score 0):

My display is the same as yours.

After the update, it seems like the `Plot Viewer` has been removed from the `Jupyter Notebook`. Before that, I can double-click any plot to open it in the viewer, or select the expand button on the upper left corner of the plot.

But it still works in the `Python Interactivate` Mode:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's a change that new release brings.

Search in **User Settings.json** with keyword `Plot Viewer`, you will find Jupyter has already set it `true` as default, which means you don't need to click the previous button and once executing the code successfully, plot output will be expanded into a plot viewer window:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to expand the plot into its own window try this

1. Install/reinstall Jupyter Notebook Renderers Extension
2. Reload Window

   Open the Command Palette (Ctrl + Shift + P)
   Then type: Reload Window

If this still doesn't work, make sure plot presentation is set to:

```
image/png
Jupyter Notebook Renderer (ms-toolsai.jupyter-renderers)
```

[Change Presentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJm7x.png)

[Select Renderer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbOCE.png)

You should now be able to generate a plot in the interactive window. Hovering over the plot will give options to expand or save.

To get a better looking plot when zoomed in enable the "Jupyter: Generate SVGPlots" setting in the "Jupyter" extension and reload the window again. Then change the plot presentation to:

```
image/svg+xml
Jupyter Notebook Renderer (ms-toolsai.jupyter-renderers)
```